# SQL: How to create a temp table and fill it with date within a select-from statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I wish to create a temp table with 1 datetime column and then fill it with date(30 days before today). I wish to do all these in a select-from statement.

I could do it with a "WITH" loop as below prior to the select-from statement. However, I wish to do it within a select-from statement.

```
declare @endDate datetime
set @endDate = dateadd(day,-30,getdate())

with CTE_Table (
    Select dataDate = dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) from CTE_Table
    where datediff(day,dataDate,@endDate) < 0
)

select * from CTE_Table
```

Please help... :....(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SELECT ... INTO`.

BTW Your recursive CTE is invalid. A fixed version is below

```
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME

SET @endDate = dateadd(day, -30, getdate());

WITH CTE_Table(dataDate)
     AS (SELECT  dateadd(day, -1, getdate())
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dateadd(day, -1, dataDate)
         FROM   CTE_Table
         WHERE  datediff(day, dataDate, @endDate) < 0)
SELECT dataDate
INTO   #T
FROM   CTE_Table
```

Comment: nicecode,
how can you append this table of dates to another table in the database

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
        DateColumn DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #temptable
SELECT dataDate FROM CTE_Table
```

Comment: Appreciate, Darren. I wish to do all this in temp table without creating any real table in DB.